# Getting "Error: No source folder defined. Check configuration" on Windows PC

Tags: nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

Helo Friends,

I am trying to do a POC with Nightwatch.js on windows machine and ended up getting the below error. Could you please help me in resolving this issue.

```
            Starting selenium server... started - PID:  12796
            Error: No source folder defined. Check configuration.
                at Function.Runner.readPaths (C:\Users\user_abc\IdeaProjects\nightwatch-cucumber-example\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\run.js:192:11)
                at Runner.runner [as run] (C:\Users\user_abc\IdeaProjects\nightwatch-cucumber-example\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\run.js:235:10)
                at CliRunner.runner (C:\Users\user_abc\IdeaProjects\nightwatch-cucumber-example\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\cli\clirunner.js:443:23)
                at C:\Users\user_abc\IdeaProjects\nightwatch-cucumber-example\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\cli\clirunner.js:395:12
                at SeleniumServer.onStarted (C:\Users\user_abc\IdeaProjects\nightwatch-cucumber-example\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\cli\clirunner.js:354:9)
                at SeleniumServer.checkProcessStarted (C:\Users\user_abc\IdeaProjects\nightwatch-cucumber-example\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\selenium.js:152:10)
                at SeleniumServer.onStderrData (C:\Users\user_abc\IdeaProjects\nightwatch-cucumber-example\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\selenium.js:132:8)
                at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
                at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
                at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
                at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
                at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
                at Pipe.onread (net.js:607:20)
            INFO Selenium process finished.
```

Comment: What is the value of `src_folders` in your nightwatch config? Is it pointing to the right directory?

Comment: Hi @tehbeardedone I can't see src_folders parameter either in nightwatch.conf.js or in package.json file. All I did was to simply follow the steps involved in [this github link](https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-cucumber-example)

Comment: Can you update your post with your nightwatch config. That project you linked works out of the box. I just pulled it down and ran it without a problem. It's hard to say what is wrong with your project without being able to see the config.

Comment: I am using the same project. Are you running it on Mac or windows ?

Comment: I ran it on windows.

Comment: That's strange, could you please point me to the location of files you wanted so that I can extract them and post it here.